# Redirection via actionListener not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm stuck with a jsf redirection via an ejb and I spend a day to find the issue without found the problem.

I want to run an action in an EJB and depending of the result, redirect the user to another page. I'm sure the function works without error, I follow the results in debug mode.

I already did the redirection by the same way in others projects but it doesn't work here, in ordre to be sure, I created a very basic function where I have the same problem.

Just to test the function I did an test ejb:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class testController implements Serializable{
    public String redirection(){
        return "login.xhtml";
    }   
}
```

and the where I try to use the fonction:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        </f:facet>
        <title>PrimeFaces Omega</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body styleClass="login-body">
        <p:commandButton value="test" actionListener="#{testController.redirection()}"/>
        </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the web.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>omega</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ttf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-sfnt</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot?#iefix</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#exosemibold</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#exobolditalic</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#exomedium</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#exoregular</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#fontawesomeregular</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I look in the log file and my function works without error but where I should be redirect to the index page the application stays on the page.

Someone could help?

Comment: Can you try to call the redirection method from "action" instead of "actionListener"?

Comment: @Kukeltje yep it is what I'm doing as I'm a student. Novice aren't welcome? Return "login.xhtml" isn't redirection? I wonder it was an implicit redirection according this https://maxkatz.org/2009/09/18/learning-jsf2-navigation/. I did a compare

Comment: @Bonifacio I tried but same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<p:commandButton> doesn't navigate when actionListener=“#{bean.method}” is declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250262/pcommandbutton-doesnt-navigate-when-actionlistener-bean-method-is-decla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component `p:commandButton` does not support action redirect using just a plain String without explicitly attaching a redirect param with it.

If you want to redirect using the action you must include `faces-redirect=true` as a url parameter in your String.

Changing your code a bit should do the trick:

```
public String redirection(){
    return "login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Comment: I agree that OP is not using the most correct way to do this, but on the other side if we always enforce that the most correct patterns must be followed we would ending up creating too much complexity and far greater learning curve for starters. I'm not saying we should turn a blind eye to this, but sometimes an easy fix can help much more than a complex tutorial.

Comment: I don't disagree, That is why I stated 'off-topic' ;-) for the tutorial, but effectively it is not fully correct since what you state in the first line is not `p:commandButton` but for a `h:commandButton` to. And for a `p\h:commandLink` to and more. And by referencing 'duplicates' there often is more information and posters can learn instead of provided with the solution (providing fish instead of learning how to fix). (see the duplicate I marked this question as)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works now by changing the action and add ?faces-redirect=true. I agree that the terminology can be better but put that on english isn't my mother lang

Comment: Great it works now. Out of curiosity, isn't your wuestion identical (95%) to the 'duplicate'? And your english is fine.  EJB vs CDI isn't realy related to that. Hint: read all Q/A in stackoverflow with 50 or more votes and remember their existence. Always handy...